# java xml SchemaFactory - loading schema with imports with different namespaces

Tags: java, xsd, xml-namespaces

I have an xsd schema with following header definition

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
            targetNamespace="vdv453ger" 
            xmlns="vdv453ger" 
            xmlns:siri="http://www.siri.org.uk/siri" 
            elementFormDefault="unqualified" 
            attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
            version="2.3e">
```

This file imports another xsd file:

```
<xsd:import namespace="http://www.siri.org.uk/siri" 
            schemaLocation="siri-1.3/siri/siri_all-v1.2.xsd"/>
```

The imported xsd schema has different namespace:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns="http://www.siri.org.uk/siri" 
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
            xmlns:acsb="http://www.ifopt.org.uk/acsb" 
            xmlns:ns1="http://datex2.eu/schema/1_0/1_0" 
            targetNamespace="http://www.siri.org.uk/siri" 
            elementFormDefault="qualified" 
            attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
            version="1.2" 
            id="siri_all">
```

When I try to load the schema with:

```
SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
mySchema = sf.newSchema( fileUrla );
```

the exception is thrown:

> `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException`: `src-include.2.1`: The targetNamespace of the referenced schema, currently `http://www.siri.org.uk/siri`, must be identical to that of the including schema, currently `vdv453ger`.

It complains that namespaces are different. How to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

The error message suggests to me that there is an xsd:include element that you haven't told us about. Use xsd:import for importing a schema document for a different namespace, xsd:include for a schema document for the same namespace.